# AS3 FS command on button

Tags: actionscript-3, button, filesystems, command

I am not very familar with AS3. 
I am trying to add this FS command on the Catalog button.

```
fscommand("exec", "c:\kdc\kdc.exe");
```

I found this for AS2

```
Catalog.onRelease = function() {
    fscommand("exec", "c:\kdc\kdc.exe");
}
```

Comment: Hello. Please specify your question

Comment: What's the issue?  did something go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an Air app?
Because if so you can use this:

```
var path:File = new File("c:\kdc\kdc.exe");
path.openWithDefaultApplication();
```

If I helped please mark as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Given the brevity of your "question", I can only assume you're looking for documentation, which you'll find here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html

That said, please review [StackOverflow's "How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have imported FSCommand so that you can use it.

import flash.system.fscommand;